# How to restart KVM network bridge after host reboot?

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization, docker

I have a KVM host on 192.168.0.4 with a bridged network adapter for one guest running on 192.168.0.9 which has been connectable to/from the entire 192.168.0.0/24 network for weeks.

Now I've had to restart the host, and the guest vm restarted too but is no longer connectable to/from anywhere on the network except for the host machine.

I can connect to it from the host machine `ssh username@192.168.0.9` and from the guest I can connect back to the host on IP 192.168.0.4, but nothing else is connectable.

I feel like there's some service missing I needed to restart after the host reboot to tell the network adapter to bridge connections outside. Or maybe that the docker network interfaces didn't initialize the firewall properly after reboot. But I don't know; what should I do?

thanks

### Output from KVM host

```
brctl show
```

> ```
> bridge name   bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
> br-238782ed063f       8000.0242e81a340a   no      
> br0       8000.7085c2060a8a   no      enp5s0
>                           vnet0
> docker0       8000.02427d14b9fa   no      
> virbr0        8000.52540044738a   yes     virbr0-nic
> ```

```
ifconfig -a
```

> ```
> br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 70:85:c2:06:0a:8a  
>           inet addr:192.168.0.4  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
>           inet6 addr: fe80::7285:c2ff:fe06:a8a/64 Scope:Link
>           UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>           RX packets:1527437 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>           TX packets:1997661 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>           collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
>           RX bytes:151534896 (151.5 MB)  TX bytes:1283893295 (1.2 GB)
>
> br-238782ed063f Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:e8:1a:34:0a  
>           inet addr:172.18.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
>           UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>           RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>           TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>           collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
>           RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
>
> docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:7d:14:b9:fa  
>           inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
>           UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>           RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>           TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>           collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
>           RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
>
> enp5s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 70:85:c2:06:0a:8a  
>           inet6 addr: fe80::7285:c2ff:fe06:a8a/64 Scope:Link
>           UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>           RX packets:1530168 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>           TX packets:2147775 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>           collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
>           RX bytes:173382480 (173.3 MB)  TX bytes:1293304788 (1.2 GB)
>
> lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
>           inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
>           inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
>           UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
>           RX packets:276 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>           TX packets:276 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>           collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
>           RX bytes:18224 (18.2 KB)  TX bytes:18224 (18.2 KB)
>
> virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:44:73:8a  
>           inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
>           UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>           RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>           TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>           collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
>           RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
>
> virbr0-nic Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:44:73:8a  
>           BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>           RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>           TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>           collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
>           RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
>
> vnet0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:54:00:5b:f5:99  
>           inet6 addr: fe80::fc54:ff:fe5b:f599/64 Scope:Link
>           UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>           RX packets:15558 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>           TX packets:20507 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>           collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
>           RX bytes:1212123 (1.2 MB)  TX bytes:1272954 (1.2 MB)
> ```

```
iptables -L -v -n
```

> ```
> Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 1448K packets, 144M bytes)
>  pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
>     0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53
>     0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:53
>     0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:67
>     0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:67
>
> Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 30647 packets, 7648K bytes)
>  pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
>     0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.122.0/24     ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
>     0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  virbr0 *       192.168.122.0/24     0.0.0.0/0           
>     0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  virbr0 virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
>     0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
>     0     0 REJECT     all  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
> 32553 8091K DOCKER-USER  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
> 32553 8091K DOCKER-ISOLATION  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
>     0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
>     0     0 DOCKER     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
>     0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
>     0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
>     0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      br-238782ed063f  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
>     0     0 DOCKER     all  --  *      br-238782ed063f  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
>     0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  br-238782ed063f !br-238782ed063f  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
>     0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  br-238782ed063f br-238782ed063f  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
>
> Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 1919K packets, 1241M bytes)
>  pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
>     0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:68
>
> Chain DOCKER (2 references)
>  pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
>
> Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION (1 references)
>  pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
>     0     0 DROP       all  --  br-238782ed063f docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
>     0     0 DROP       all  --  docker0 br-238782ed063f  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
> 32553 8091K RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
>
> Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
>  pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
> 32553 8091K RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
> ```

Comment: Please show us the output of `brctl show`.

Comment: And `ifconfig -a` and `iptables -L -v -n`.

Comment: @TamerlanAbu thanks, I've added `brctl show`

Comment: @MikhailKhirgiy thanks for following up. I've added the output from `ifconfig` and `iptables`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `iptables`. The `FORWARD` table doesn't allow any traffic via the `br0` interface and has `DROP` default rule.

To resolve the problem you need to clear all rules in the `FORWARD` table and assign default `ACCEPT` policy on it:

```
iptables -F FORWARD
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
```